# Remove headings option from Wysiwyg editor from ACF in a certain custom post type

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

I want to remove the headings options from Wysiwyg in a custom field that is set ix certain custom post type. Is there a way to archive it?

Answer (score 1):

You can generally edit the capability of the tinyMCE WYSIWYG Editor for ACF with the `acf/fields/wysiwyg/toolbars` hook.

By default the WYSIWYG editor has two toolbars, "Full" and "Basic" but you can also create you own([see docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/customize-the-wysiwyg-toolbars/))

Removing the formatting option for the "Full" WYSIWYG editor can be accomplished like this:

```
add_filter( 'acf/fields/wysiwyg/toolbars' , 'my_toolbars'  );
function my_toolbars( $toolbars )
{
    // Edit the "Full" toolbar and remove 'code'
    // - delet from array code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key
    if( ($key = array_search('formatselect' , $toolbars['Full' ][2])) !== false )
    {
        unset( $toolbars['Full' ][2][$key] );
    }
}
```

SRC: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/customize-the-wysiwyg-toolbars/